# ValueError: Tensor:(...) is not an element of this graph

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I am using keras' pre-trained model and the error came up when trying to get predictions. I have the following code in flask server:

```
from NeuralNetwork import *

@app.route("/uploadMultipleImages", methods=["POST"])
def uploadMultipleImages():
    uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("file[]")
    getPredictionfunction = preTrainedModel["VGG16"]

    for file in uploaded_files:
        path = os.path.join(STATIC_PATH, file.filename)
        result = getPredictionfunction(path)
```

This is what I have in my NeuralNetwork.py file:

```
vgg16 = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
def getVGG16Prediction(img_path):

    model = vgg16
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)

    pred = model.predict(x) #ERROR HERE
    return sort(decode_predictions(pred, top=3)[0])

preTrainedModel["VGG16"] = getVGG16Prediction
```

However, running this code below, does not create any error:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    STATIC_PATH = os.getcwd()+"/static"
    print(preTrainedModel["VGG16"](STATIC_PATH+"/18.jpg"))
```

Here is the full error:
[image]

Any comment or suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the backend is set to tensorflow. You should set the Keras session to the graph of tensorflow

```
from tensorflow import Graph, Session
from keras import backend 
model = 'model path'
graph1 = Graph()
with graph1.as_default():
    session1 = Session(graph=graph1)
    with session1.as_default():
        model_1.load_model(model) # depends on your model type

model2 = 'model path2'
graph2 = Graph()
with graph2.as_default():
    session2 = Session(graph=graph2)
    with session2.as_default():
        model_2.load_model(model2) # depends on your model type
```

and for predicting

```
K.set_session(session#)
with graph#.as_default():
    prediction = model_#.predict(img_data)
```

Comment: Worked for me, just had to change `from keras import backend` to  'from keras import backend as K`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** What I wrote below **doesn't seem to work** when deploying the application (I was just testing locally until now). The model in app.config is loaded too often it seems. (at each request?)

Coincidentally I had the same problem yesterday. It seems there are some problems between the interaction of TensorFlow and Flask. Unfortunately I don't know enough about the internals of either one to really understand the problem but I can provide a hack which helped me get it to work. (Note: I was using Python3 but I don't think this makes a difference here.)

The problem seems to occur when initializing a model in the global namespace of your flask application. Therefore I loaded the model directly into app.config:

```
app.config.update({"MODEL":VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)})
# ...
app.config["MODEL"].predict(x)
```

Maybe you can load the model in your server.py instead of your NeuralNetwork.py and pass it to `getVGG16Prediction` together with `img_path`?

Comment: In my case, the problem was because flask was loading tensor flow twice. When I changed app.run(debug=False) then it works, but I do not know why. Here is the link to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015797/is-tensorflow-loading-twice-in-pycharm. I'm not sure if it's the same in your case, but I hope it helps. Thank you for your suggestion :)